# Extrapolating data using interp linear interpolation for water quality data visualizations

Tags: r, data-visualization, interpolation

**Background:** I'm working on creating data visualizations from water quality data. The code I have works great for the most part, but sometimes we have to drop data from the surface if it's too choppy to get good data, so we end up with data starting at 2m (sometimes 3m) depth. When we drop the values, the interpolation returns NA values at the surface, making the visualizations unusable for our purpose. See images for examples: [Example of a good visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdh6S.png) [Example of visualization with surface NAs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2ISQ.png)

**Example data snip and further explanation below code**

The akima::interp function does not allow for extrapolation when using linear interpolation, and the non-linear option isn't appropriate for our data.

I'm looking for a workaround for this. My thoughts were either:

1. a line of code that does something like: "if minimum depth at station is greater than 1, copy data from minimum depth to all depths between 1 and the minimum" (disclaimer: I know this isn't appropriate for analysis, but for our purposes creating visualizations to show data trends we are okay with this)
2. something I'm missing within the function that will allow for extrapolation (or using a different linear interpolation function)

Here is the code I have so far (this is taken from within a larger function).

```
library(akima); library(dplyr)
library("data.table");library(tidyverse);library(naniar)
library(magrittr);library(janitor);library(lubridate);library(wql)

 ##Example data import
 
example.data<-structure(list(Station = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 
23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 
27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 
29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 
32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 34, 34, 649, 649, 649, 649, 649, 649, 649, 649, 649, 
649, 657, 657, 657, 657, 657, 657, 657, 657, 657, 657), Distance.from.36 = c(127.7053, 
127.7053, 127.7053, 127.7053, 127.7053, 127.7053, 127.7053, 127.7053, 
127.7053, 127.7053, 125.3243, 125.3243, 125.3243, 125.3243, 125.3243, 
125.3243, 125.3243, 125.3243, 125.3243, 125.3243, 119.8957, 119.8957, 
119.8957, 119.8957, 119.8957, 119.8957, 119.8957, 119.8957, 119.8957, 
119.8957, 119.8957, 119.8957, 119.8957, 119.8957, 119.8957, 119.8957, 
115.6252, 115.6252, 115.6252, 115.6252, 115.6252, 115.6252, 115.6252, 
115.6252, 115.6252, 115.6252, 115.6252, 115.6252, 110.8977, 110.8977, 
110.8977, 110.8977, 110.8977, 110.8977, 110.8977, 110.8977, 110.8977, 
110.8977, 104.981, 104.981, 104.981, 104.981, 104.981, 104.981, 
104.981, 104.981, 104.981, 104.981, 104.981, 104.981, 104.981, 
99.7699, 99.7699, 99.7699, 99.7699, 99.7699, 99.7699, 99.7699, 
99.7699, 99.7699, 99.7699, 99.7699, 99.7699, 99.7699, 99.7699, 
99.7699, 96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 
96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 
96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 
96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 96.7889, 93.5951, 93.5951, 
93.5951, 93.5951, 93.5951, 93.5951, 93.5951, 93.5951, 93.5951, 
93.5951, 93.5951, 93.5951, 93.5951, 93.5951, 93.5951, 93.5951, 
93.5951, 89.7672, 89.7672, 89.7672, 89.7672, 89.7672, 89.7672, 
89.7672, 89.7672, 89.7672, 89.7672, 89.7672, 89.7672, 89.7672, 
84.4458, 84.4458, 84.4458, 84.4458, 84.4458, 84.4458, 84.4458, 
84.4458, 78.5444, 78.5444, 78.5444, 78.5444, 78.5444, 78.5444, 
78.5444, 78.5444, 78.5444, 74.4288, 74.4288, 74.4288, 74.4288, 
74.4288, 74.4288, 74.4288, 74.4288, 74.4288, 74.4288, 74.4288, 
74.4288, 74.4288, 74.4288, 69.9895, 69.9895, 69.9895, 69.9895, 
69.9895, 69.9895, 69.9895, 69.9895, 69.9895, 69.9895, 69.9895, 
69.9895, 69.9895, 69.9895, 69.9895, 69.9895, 69.9895, 69.9895, 
69.9895, 69.9895, 69.9895, 69.9895, 63.0794, 63.0794, 63.0794, 
63.0794, 63.0794, 63.0794, 63.0794, 63.0794, 63.0794, 63.0794, 
63.0794, 58.8909, 58.8909, 58.8909, 58.8909, 58.8909, 58.8909, 
58.8909, 58.8909, 58.8909, 58.8909, 58.8909, 58.8909, 54.9481, 
54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 
54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 
54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 
54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 
54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 
54.9481, 54.9481, 54.9481, 51.4501, 51.4501, 51.4501, 51.4501, 
51.4501, 51.4501, 51.4501, 51.4501, 51.4501, 51.4501, 51.4501, 
51.4501, 51.4501, 51.4501, 51.4501, 51.4501, 51.4501, 51.4501, 
51.4501, 51.4501, 51.4501, 51.4501, 51.4501, 51.4501, 46.6266, 
46.6266, 46.6266, 46.6266, 46.6266, 46.6266, 46.6266, 46.6266, 
46.6266, 46.6266, 46.6266, 46.6266, 46.6266, 46.6266, 46.6266, 
46.6266, 43.921, 43.921, 43.921, 43.921, 43.921, 43.921, 43.921, 
43.921, 43.921, 43.921, 43.921, 43.921, 43.921, 43.921, 43.921, 
43.921, 43.921, 39.6557, 39.6557, 39.6557, 39.6557, 39.6557, 
39.6557, 39.6557, 39.6557, 39.6557, 39.6557, 39.6557, 39.6557, 
39.6557, 37.0911, 37.0911, 37.0911, 37.0911, 37.0911, 37.0911, 
37.0911, 37.0911, 32.8382, 32.8382, 32.8382, 32.8382, 32.8382, 
32.8382, 28.756, 28.756, 28.756, 28.756, 28.756, 28.756, 28.756, 
28.756, 26.1872, 26.1872, 26.1872, 26.1872, 26.1872, 26.1872, 
26.1872, 26.1872, 26.1872, 26.1872, 23.5695, 23.5695, 23.5695, 
23.5695, 23.5695, 23.5695, 23.5695, 23.5695, 23.5695, 23.5695, 
23.5695, 23.5695, 20.2526, 20.2526, 20.2526, 20.2526, 20.2526, 
20.2526, 20.2526, 20.2526, 20.2526, 20.2526, 20.2526, 17.564, 
17.564, 17.564, 17.564, 17.564, 17.564, 17.564, 17.564, 17.564, 
17.564, 17.564, 17.564, 14.7543, 14.7543, 14.7543, 14.7543, 14.7543, 
14.7543, 14.7543, 14.7543, 14.7543, 14.7543, 10.6065, 10.6065, 
10.6065, 10.6065, 10.6065, 10.6065, 10.6065, 10.6065, 10.6065, 
10.6065, 8.1507, 8.1507, 8.1507, 8.1507, 8.1507, 8.1507, 8.1507, 
8.1507, 6.8085, 6.8085, 6.8085, 6.8085, 6.8085, 6.8085, 6.8085, 
6.8085, 6.8085, 6.8085, 3.529, 3.529, 132.9388, 132.9388, 132.9388, 
132.9388, 132.9388, 132.9388, 132.9388, 132.9388, 132.9388, 132.9388, 
147.2548, 147.2548, 147.2548, 147.2548, 147.2548, 147.2548, 147.2548, 
147.2548, 147.2548, 147.2548), Depth = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), Calc.Chl = c(3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 
3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.2, 3.4, 3.4, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.7, 3.5, 
3.4, 3.6, 3.6, 3.7, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.5, 3.4, 
3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.4, 3.9, 3.9, 3.8, 3.9, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 
3.8, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.6, 4.4, 4.4, 4.3, 4.4, 4.3, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 
4, 4.1, 3.3, 3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.9, 2.8, 2.6, 2.8, 2.8, 2.7, 2.7, 
2.7, 2.8, 3.1, 3.1, 2.8, 2.5, 2.5, 2.4, 2.2, 2.2, 2.1, 2, 1.7, 
1.9, 2, 2.1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.2, 2, 2, 2, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.8, 1.7, 
1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.8, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 2, 1.9, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
1.2, 1.9, 1.9, 1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.7, 
1.4, 1.3, 1.8, 2, 1.2, 1.7, 1.7, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 
1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 2.9, 2.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 4.5, 
3.8, 2.8, 2.3, 2.8, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 2.9, 3.8, 3.6, 3.1, 3, 3.1, 
3, 2.9, 2.6, 3, 3.1, 2.8, 2.6, 2.8, 2.3, 4, 3.8, 3.2, 2.8, 2.6, 
2.5, 2.7, 2.6, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.7, 2.6, 2.7, 3, 3, 
2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 4.1, 4.3, 4.4, 4.3, 4.3, 4.4, 4.6, 4.8, 4.9, 
4.8, 4.8, 3.6, 4, 4.2, 4.2, 4, 4.3, 4.9, 5.1, 5.5, 5.5, 5.3, 
5.7, 4.1, 5, 4.7, 4.9, 4.9, 5.2, 5.2, 5.2, 5.2, 5, 4.9, 4.9, 
5.1, 5.1, 5.3, 5.2, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.7, 5.3, 5.2, 5.2, 5.4, 5.6, 
5.8, 5.8, 5.8, 5.8, 6, 6.1, 6, 6, 6, 5.9, 6, 5.8, 6.1, 6, 4.5, 
5, 5.1, 4.5, 4.6, 4.5, 4.5, 4.4, 4.4, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.4, 4.6, 
4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.7, 4.9, 4.8, 4.5, 4.9, 5.3, 5.6, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 
4.2, 4.2, 4.4, 4.4, 4.3, 4.4, 4.4, 4.5, 4.8, 4.7, 4.7, 4.9, 5.1, 
4.1, 3.9, 3.9, 3.9, 3.8, 3.8, 3.9, 4, 4.2, 4.3, 4.5, 4.6, 5, 
5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.2, 6.2, 5.7, 4.5, 4.1, 4.1, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 4.3, 
4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.6, 4.3, 4.2, 4.1, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 4.3, 4.7, 
4.6, 4.6, 4.6, 4.6, 4.6, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.1, 4.1, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 
4.8, 4.6, 4.6, 4.6, 4.6, 4.5, 4.4, 4.3, 4.3, 4.4, 4.7, 4.6, 4.7, 
4.6, 4.5, 4.4, 4.3, 4.2, 4.3, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 5.5, 5.4, 5.3, 5.1, 
5, 4.9, 4.9, 5, 5, 5.1, 5, 7.1, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 6.8, 6.8, 6.7, 
6.5, 6.4, 6.1, 5.5, 5.3, 7.3, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.1, 6.8, 6.6, 6.4, 
6.2, 6, 7.3, 8.2, 8.8, 9.6, 10.4, 10.5, 10.8, 11.1, 11.3, 11.4, 
6.7, 6.6, 6.8, 6.9, 6.9, 7.3, 7.6, 7.8, 8.2, 8.2, 8.2, 8.1, 8.1, 
8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.5, 8.3, 8.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.1, 
3.1, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.4, 2.2, 2.3, 2.2, 
2.1), DO = c(91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 
91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 
91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 
91L, 91L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 91L, 90L, 90L, 89L, 
89L, 89L, 89L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 89L, 89L, 
89L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 
87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 90L, 90L, 89L, 
88L, 88L, 88L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 
87L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 
86L, 89L, 87L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 85L, 89L, 87L, 86L, 86L, 
86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 85L, 87L, 87L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 
85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 88L, 87L, 87L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 
85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 
85L, 85L, 87L, 87L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 
84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 86L, 
86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 84L, 
84L, 84L, 84L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 
82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 85L, 
84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 
84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 85L, 85L, 84L, 
84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 
86L, 86L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 
84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 92L, 90L, 89L, 88L, 88L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 
87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 90L, 90L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 90L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 90L, 
90L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 91L, 90L, 90L, 89L, 
89L, 89L, 89L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 
91L, 90L, 89L, 88L, 87L, 87L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 
85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 82L, 83L, 83L, 84L, 84L, 
85L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 74L, 74L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
90L), Calc.SPM = c(35L, 38L, 37L, 39L, 42L, 42L, 45L, 48L, 46L, 
46L, 46L, 44L, 46L, 52L, 50L, 53L, 59L, 67L, 65L, 65L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 40L, 42L, 41L, 41L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 
49L, 47L, 47L, 46L, 48L, 48L, 51L, 55L, 55L, 65L, 66L, 70L, 72L, 
55L, 55L, 60L, 60L, 62L, 68L, 71L, 69L, 77L, 72L, 47L, 54L, 60L, 
63L, 68L, 74L, 94L, 94L, 106L, 123L, 120L, 127L, 130L, 36L, 33L, 
31L, 34L, 34L, 41L, 55L, 68L, 87L, 114L, 168L, 204L, 226L, 240L, 
262L, 42L, 44L, 54L, 58L, 52L, 52L, 51L, 50L, 58L, 68L, 90L, 
118L, 156L, 174L, 180L, 187L, 180L, 190L, 189L, 187L, 187L, 185L, 
184L, 183L, 192L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 35L, 40L, 
41L, 45L, 48L, 53L, 78L, 169L, 186L, 195L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 27L, 
29L, 32L, 32L, 41L, 65L, 70L, 67L, 66L, 69L, 27L, 29L, 74L, 102L, 
148L, 141L, 149L, 217L, 24L, 25L, 33L, 88L, 118L, 133L, 170L, 
223L, 225L, 27L, 32L, 36L, 41L, 45L, 52L, 66L, 106L, 110L, 106L, 
113L, 136L, 149L, 185L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 28L, 33L, 40L, 
60L, 72L, 76L, 84L, 90L, 92L, 91L, 91L, 90L, 89L, 86L, 85L, 84L, 
86L, 15L, 14L, 15L, 14L, 20L, 29L, 32L, 34L, 34L, 37L, 45L, 14L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 40L, 47L, 53L, 67L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
18L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 27L, 30L, 28L, 26L, 25L, 24L, 25L, 13L, 
14L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 21L, 20L, 23L, 22L, 25L, 36L, 39L, 41L, 30L, 34L, 40L, 
47L, 53L, 56L, 62L, 64L, 67L, 70L, 88L, 93L, 87L, 89L, 98L, 109L, 
17L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 28L, 38L, 50L, 63L, 70L, 100L, 
118L, 117L, 128L, 135L, 124L, 22L, 19L, 18L, 26L, 42L, 51L, 63L, 
65L, 70L, 68L, 70L, 79L, 92L, 31L, 31L, 30L, 31L, 35L, 38L, 42L, 
44L, 47L, 45L, 48L, 50L, 51L, 50L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 31L, 54L, 
58L, 56L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 27L, 27L, 25L, 24L, 26L, 30L, 34L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 22L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 24L, 23L, 25L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 28L, 31L, 36L, 34L, 36L, 34L, 24L, 26L, 28L, 28L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 37L, 27L, 27L, 29L, 29L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 25L, 25L, 23L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 43L, 
45L, 43L, 67L, 72L, 75L, 82L, 96L, 137L, 142L, 105L, 245L, 264L, 
267L, 279L, 248L, 224L, 180L, 137L, 104L, 98L, 293L, 294L, 33L, 
35L, 36L, 36L, 35L, 34L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L), Salinity = c(0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 
0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 
0.08, 0.08, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 
0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 
0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 
0.16, 0.66, 0.65, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 
2.97, 3.12, 3.15, 3.16, 3.17, 3.17, 3.16, 3.16, 3.2, 3.23, 3.23, 
3.24, 3.24, 3.86, 4.2, 4.57, 4.68, 4.7, 5, 5.26, 5.5, 5.84, 6.05, 
6.12, 6.13, 6.12, 6.12, 6.12, 6.01, 6.23, 6.78, 7.03, 7.16, 7.25, 
7.35, 7.34, 7.74, 8.05, 8.25, 8.38, 8.54, 8.59, 8.59, 8.6, 8.58, 
8.61, 8.61, 8.63, 8.63, 8.64, 8.63, 8.64, 8.64, 6.87, 6.88, 6.93, 
7.37, 7.67, 7.89, 8.09, 8.34, 8.5, 8.54, 8.57, 8.67, 8.81, 9.28, 
10.01, 10.07, 10.09, 9.45, 9.5, 9.53, 9.74, 9.92, 10.11, 10.23, 
10.94, 11.77, 11.87, 11.79, 11.77, 11.85, 13.1, 13.71, 14.52, 
14.63, 14.98, 15.06, 15.06, 15.05, 16.77, 17.64, 18.82, 20.03, 
20.27, 20.33, 20.48, 20.56, 20.57, 20.6, 21.19, 21.56, 21.66, 
21.73, 21.78, 21.83, 21.88, 21.87, 21.87, 21.88, 21.89, 21.89, 
21.89, 20.12, 20.13, 20.23, 20.31, 20.65, 21.24, 21.62, 21.87, 
22.12, 22.18, 22.24, 22.34, 22.45, 22.53, 22.55, 22.53, 22.53, 
22.52, 22.56, 22.57, 22.57, 22.56, 23.69, 25.05, 25.27, 25.53, 
26.04, 26.32, 26.36, 26.38, 26.41, 26.46, 26.46, 25.11, 25.72, 
25.97, 26.19, 26.59, 26.97, 27.05, 27.09, 27.15, 27.15, 27.22, 
27.22, 27.36, 27.43, 27.48, 27.44, 27.33, 27.26, 27.27, 27.33, 
27.37, 27.57, 27.68, 27.72, 27.79, 28.01, 28.19, 28.38, 28.47, 
28.48, 28.48, 28.57, 28.66, 28.68, 28.8, 28.85, 28.92, 28.93, 
28.95, 28.95, 28.95, 28.93, 28.93, 28.93, 28.91, 28.9, 28.91, 
28.91, 28.92, 28.92, 28.92, 26.77, 26.95, 27.12, 27.26, 27.35, 
27.33, 27.39, 27.41, 27.44, 27.46, 27.46, 27.47, 27.51, 27.58, 
27.61, 27.62, 27.66, 27.71, 27.82, 27.73, 27.87, 27.94, 27.94, 
27.94, 26.28, 26.32, 26.42, 26.48, 26.55, 26.59, 26.62, 26.62, 
26.64, 26.65, 26.65, 26.65, 26.66, 26.66, 26.65, 26.65, 25.74, 
25.9, 25.91, 26.16, 26.23, 26.25, 26.37, 26.45, 26.48, 26.49, 
26.5, 26.52, 26.53, 26.53, 26.53, 26.53, 26.53, 24.72, 25, 25.13, 
25.3, 25.43, 25.46, 25.49, 25.49, 25.5, 25.49, 25.49, 25.5, 25.5, 
25.36, 25.36, 25.36, 25.36, 25.35, 25.35, 25.34, 25.34, 24.45, 
24.45, 24.45, 24.45, 24.44, 24.44, 23.78, 23.78, 23.78, 23.78, 
23.8, 23.81, 23.81, 23.81, 23.56, 23.56, 23.56, 23.58, 23.63, 
23.68, 23.72, 23.73, 23.74, 23.74, 23.31, 23.31, 23.31, 23.33, 
23.37, 23.47, 23.51, 23.58, 23.61, 23.61, 23.66, 23.74, 23.12, 
23.16, 23.22, 23.26, 23.27, 23.27, 23.29, 23.33, 23.36, 23.38, 
23.39, 23.05, 23.05, 23.06, 23.07, 23.08, 23.08, 23.09, 23.1, 
23.12, 23.18, 23.25, 23.27, 22.63, 22.63, 22.7, 22.87, 22.89, 
22.9, 22.93, 22.95, 22.98, 23.01, 22.33, 22.47, 22.51, 22.55, 
22.58, 22.6, 22.62, 22.64, 22.68, 22.72, 21.29, 21.67, 21.67, 
21.66, 21.68, 21.74, 21.9, 22.15, 20.73, 20.83, 20.91, 21.02, 
21.1, 21.25, 21.39, 21.5, 21.68, 21.83, 20.46, 20.51, 0.06, 0.06, 
0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 
0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06), Temperature = c(19.14, 
19.12, 19.11, 19.09, 19.08, 19.08, 19.06, 19.05, 19.06, 19.06, 
19.1, 19.11, 19.09, 19.07, 19.07, 19.06, 19.06, 19.05, 19.05, 
19.05, 19.32, 19.32, 19.33, 19.32, 19.32, 19.32, 19.32, 19.31, 
19.3, 19.3, 19.3, 19.3, 19.3, 19.3, 19.3, 19.29, 19.71, 19.71, 
19.72, 19.7, 19.7, 19.68, 19.65, 19.66, 19.62, 19.62, 19.62, 
19.62, 19.78, 19.79, 19.76, 19.76, 19.74, 19.72, 19.72, 19.72, 
19.71, 19.71, 19.63, 19.54, 19.5, 19.49, 19.48, 19.45, 19.39, 
19.39, 19.35, 19.32, 19.33, 19.31, 19.3, 19.47, 19.21, 18.91, 
18.86, 18.86, 18.81, 18.76, 18.72, 18.67, 18.64, 18.63, 18.63, 
18.63, 18.63, 18.63, 18.93, 18.85, 18.7, 18.65, 18.64, 18.63, 
18.62, 18.62, 18.56, 18.51, 18.48, 18.45, 18.42, 18.41, 18.41, 
18.41, 18.41, 18.4, 18.41, 18.41, 18.41, 18.41, 18.41, 18.41, 
18.41, 19.24, 19.21, 19.09, 18.62, 18.56, 18.5, 18.47, 18.45, 
18.43, 18.44, 18.44, 18.44, 18.44, 18.41, 18.34, 18.34, 18.33, 
18.72, 18.66, 18.65, 18.5, 18.39, 18.3, 18.28, 18.21, 18.13, 
18.12, 18.13, 18.13, 18.12, 19.18, 18.47, 18.05, 18.02, 17.96, 
17.95, 17.95, 17.95, 18.36, 17.55, 17.21, 16.85, 16.78, 16.76, 
16.71, 16.69, 16.69, 16.84, 16.61, 16.51, 16.45, 16.42, 16.39, 
16.37, 16.34, 16.34, 16.34, 16.34, 16.33, 16.33, 16.32, 17.11, 
17.05, 16.88, 16.81, 16.69, 16.52, 16.4, 16.31, 16.21, 16.19, 
16.17, 16.14, 16.12, 16.1, 16.1, 16.1, 16.1, 16.11, 16.11, 16.11, 
16.11, 16.12, 16.32, 15.69, 15.54, 15.46, 15.2, 15.05, 15.02, 
15.01, 14.99, 14.96, 14.96, 15.28, 15.16, 15.09, 15.04, 14.93, 
14.77, 14.74, 14.72, 14.69, 14.69, 14.66, 14.65, 14.77, 14.74, 
14.71, 14.73, 14.8, 14.83, 14.83, 14.8, 14.78, 14.66, 14.59, 
14.57, 14.52, 14.39, 14.27, 14.15, 14.09, 14.09, 14.09, 14.03, 
13.97, 13.96, 13.89, 13.86, 13.8, 13.79, 13.77, 13.77, 13.77, 
13.78, 13.78, 13.78, 13.78, 13.78, 13.78, 13.78, 13.77, 13.77, 
13.77, 14.97, 14.87, 14.77, 14.7, 14.65, 14.67, 14.65, 14.64, 
14.63, 14.62, 14.62, 14.61, 14.59, 14.54, 14.52, 14.5, 14.49, 
14.47, 14.4, 14.45, 14.38, 14.34, 14.34, 14.34, 15.6, 15.58, 
15.53, 15.49, 15.46, 15.44, 15.43, 15.43, 15.41, 15.39, 15.38, 
15.38, 15.38, 15.38, 15.39, 15.4, 15.69, 15.63, 15.63, 15.58, 
15.58, 15.59, 15.57, 15.53, 15.5, 15.49, 15.48, 15.46, 15.45, 
15.45, 15.44, 15.44, 15.45, 17.95, 17.59, 17.42, 17.15, 16.93, 
16.87, 16.83, 16.81, 16.8, 16.81, 16.8, 16.79, 16.79, 17.2, 17.2, 
17.2, 17.2, 17.21, 17.21, 17.22, 17.22, 18.16, 18.16, 18.16, 
18.16, 18.16, 18.16, 18.88, 18.88, 18.88, 18.88, 18.87, 18.86, 
18.86, 18.86, 19.34, 19.35, 19.34, 19.33, 19.26, 19.13, 19, 18.97, 
18.96, 18.96, 19.76, 19.76, 19.77, 19.75, 19.68, 19.46, 19.37, 
19.2, 19.14, 19.12, 19.03, 18.88, 20.13, 20.1, 19.98, 19.88, 
19.86, 19.85, 19.81, 19.77, 19.73, 19.7, 19.68, 20.28, 20.27, 
20.26, 20.25, 20.24, 20.23, 20.21, 20.18, 20.13, 19.96, 19.78, 
19.76, 20.48, 20.48, 20.46, 20.31, 20.27, 20.25, 20.23, 20.2, 
20.19, 20.17, 20.38, 20.36, 20.37, 20.36, 20.33, 20.31, 20.31, 
20.31, 20.29, 20.26, 20.51, 20.43, 20.39, 20.37, 20.34, 20.22, 
20.06, 19.91, 20.53, 20.49, 20.48, 20.46, 20.47, 20.48, 20.48, 
20.48, 20.49, 20.48, 19.47, 19.43, 19.11, 19.1, 19.08, 19.09, 
19.09, 19.09, 19.09, 19.1, 19.1, 19.11, 18.22, 18.22, 18.23, 
18.22, 18.2, 18.2, 18.2, 18.2, 18.2, 18.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-453L))

##Setting up data
example.data$Date<-'06/10/2005'
example.data$Date<-as.Date(example.data$Date,"%m/%d/%Y")
d_date<-example.data[example.data$Date=='2005-06-10',]
d_date<-drop_na(d_date,c(Calc.Chl,DO,Calc.SPM,Salinity,Temperature))
d_date$logDepth<-log10(d_date$Depth)

 
  ##add a line, if minimum depth @station > 1, copy minimum as all depths between 1 and min

 #Interpolations
interp.chl <- interp(d_date$Distance.from.36, d_date$logDepth, d_date$Calc.Chl, nx = 1000, ny = 800,yo=seq(0,max(d_date$logDepth), length = 800))
interp.df.chl <- interp.chl %>% interp2xyz() %>% as.data.frame()
names(interp.df.chl) <- c("x", "y", "Chl")

interp.do <- interp(d_date$Distance.from.36, d_date$logDepth, d_date$DO, nx = 1000, ny = 800,yo=seq(0,max(d_date$logDepth), length = 800))
interp.df.do <- interp.do %>% interp2xyz() %>% as.data.frame()
names(interp.df.do) <- c("x", "y", "Oxy")

interp.spm <- interp(d_date$Distance.from.36, d_date$logDepth, d_date$Calc.SPM, nx = 1000, ny = 800,yo=seq(0,max(d_date$logDepth), length = 800))
interp.df.spm <- interp.spm %>% interp2xyz() %>% as.data.frame()
names(interp.df.spm) <- c("x", "y", "SPM")

interp.sal <- interp(d_date$Distance.from.36, d_date$logDepth, d_date$Salinity, nx = 1000, ny = 800,yo=seq(0,max(d_date$logDepth), length = 800))
interp.df.sal <- interp.sal %>% interp2xyz() %>% as.data.frame()
names(interp.df.sal) <- c("x", "y", "Sal")

interp.temp <- interp(d_date$Distance.from.36, d_date$logDepth, d_date$Temperature, nx = 1000, ny = 800,yo=seq(0,max(d_date$logDepth), length = 800))
interp.df.temp <- interp.temp %>% interp2xyz() %>% as.data.frame()
names(interp.df.temp) <- c("x", "y", "Temp")
```

For context, our data is organized by date/station/depth, where each date is sampled at many locations (stations), at depths in 1m increments. If we drop surface data, there is no 1m depth, and the first depth is 2. [Here is a snip of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VbnM.png) of two stations within one date that one minimum depth is 1m and the second is 2m.

TIA!

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by pasting a sample of your data: use `dput(your_data_sample)` This allows others to test and verify solutions.

Comment: @Peter, I added example data. Thank you for the suggestion.